# jAlert is not calling in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am validating a text box by entering the enter key in key board. The validation works fine but the JAlert is not showing. but when i call the same function on the button click it shows the alert in IE.  I am totally confused with this. Can any one help me? [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BpacU/)

```
function isEnterPressed(event) {
        var keynum;
        if (window.event) {
            keynum = event.keyCode;
        }else if (event.which) {
            keynum = event.which;
        }
        if(keynum == 13) {
            searchSubmit();
        }
    }
```

searchSubmit() is a function call on the button click also

```
function searchSubmit()
{
    // some valdation
  if(!flag) 
    {
    alert('flag'+flag);
    jAlert("Enter anyone of the value to search");
    return false;  
    }else{
    document.userManagementUsers.action=baseUrl;
    document.userManagementUsers.submit();
    }
 }
```

alert('flag'+flag) is displaying by clicking the enter key jalert is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$('body').jAlert('Enter anyone of the value to search', 'success');
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').jAlert('Enter anyone of the value to search', "success");
});
```

Comment: $('body').jAlert() is not a function